# taking input in a matrix of variable size in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, compiler-errors, orthogonal

I am trying to check the orthogonality of a matrix A in c++.
For that I am declaring a "MAX" value of number of rows and columns, then I am trying to get the number of rows and columns for the matrix, hence declaring it.
After that I am trying to get the input for the matrix elements by using pointer to the rows of the matrix and so on ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10
int arows,acolumns; /*line 4*/
void input_matix(float (*arr)[MAX],int arows,int acolumns)
{/*asks user for input of individual elements*/}

void transpose(float (*T)[MAX],float (*A)[MAX],int arows,int acolumns)
{/*gets me the transpose*/}
void product(float (*A)[MAX],float (*T)[MAX],float (*P)[MAX])
{/*multiplies two matrices and places the product in P matrix*/}

int orthogonal_array(float (*arr)[MAX]){/*returns 1 if arr is ortho*/}
int main()
{
    //int arows,acolumns;
    printf("Enter the no. of rows and columns of matrix A: \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&arows,&acolumns);
    float A[arows][acolumns];

    if (arows != acolumns)
    {
        printf("Not a orthogonal matrix.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        input_matix(A,arows,acolumns);
        orthogonal_array(A);
    }
}
```

When compiling it I am getting the error

```
cannot convert 'float (*)[acolumns] to float (*)[10]'
```

I have tried replacing line 4 with

```
extern int arows,acolumns;
```

and replacing float (*arr)[MAX] by
`float arr[][acolumns]` similarly other parameters in the functions but then I get the error that

```
"expression must have a constant value"
"array bound is not a integer constant before "]" token */
```

Please suggest me what should I do, so as to make these functions work properly

Comment: In `main()` define `float A[MAX][MAX];` but use only what you need: use `arows` and `acolumns`; waste `MAX - arows`, waste `MAX - acolumns`.

Comment: BTW: always prefer `double` when using floating-point except if you have a **very strong** reason to do otherwise (because your teacher told you to use `float` is not a **very strong** reason :).

Comment: Pick one language. The title says C. The body says C++. The error message suggests C++. The tag says C. Which language do you want to program in? The changes needed depend on the language.

Comment: For a simple workaround, change `float A[arows][acolumns]` to `float A[MAX][MAX]`. There are more efficient ways to support variably sized arrays in C++, but it looks like you may not have learned them yet.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that in C++ VLA (Varibale Length Arrays) are not allowed. It is not a part of the language C++ so far.

`float A[arows][acolumns];`

is invalid C++ code.

In C you can do, but not in C++

Answer (score -1):

In C, you can't create double index array or change its size during the program.
So yes, you have to tell the programme what's the size of A before compiling.

You can create this array with its max size and send "arows" and "acolumns" with it in your functions to work only on "used space" instead.

Comment: C does allow “double index” arrays; `float A[arows][acolumns]` is a proper declaration. And C does allow variable length arrays, although support is not mandatory.

Comment: Sure it does ! Maybe I don't explained it very well. I meant that you can't change its size after the compilation.

Comment: C does allow arrays whose sizes are specified after compilation, during program execution.

Comment: Well I didn't know about that. So can you answer his question ? I'm curious !